# Avoid looping over array multiple times to rearrange elements

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I have to rearrange an array of objects based on certain property values, but I'm struggling with how to avoid looping over the array multiple times.

```
      // first move the labels to the front
      entry.response.forEach( (resp, idx) => {
        if (resp.metadata.response_label && resp.metadata.response_label !== '') {
          rearrangeArray(entry.response, idx, 0);
        }
      });

      // second move the enums in front of the labels
      entry.response.forEach( (resp, idx) => {
        if (resp.metadata.response_type === "enum") {
          rearrangeArray(entry.response, idx, 0);
        }
      });
```

Firstly, if the response enum exists I need to move those to the front of the array. If a label exists, they need to be moved to the front of the array *but after* the enum types. The `rearrangeArray` function also ends up basically looping over the array as well, so this code is pretty inefficient.

Are there any patterns or lodash functions that could help optimize this process?

UPDATE: my `rearrangeArray` function takes the array, then the old index, then the new index (arr, old_index, new_index)

Comment: could you provide an example entry and expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will sort the array into two arrays then join them. I am not sure what you are doing with the rearrangeArray so you will have use this is an example not a final solution.

```
var labels = [];
var enums = [];
entry.response.forEach( (resp, idx) => {
  if (resp.metadata.response_label && resp.metadata.response_label !== '') {
    labels.push(resp)
    //rearrangeArray(entry.response, idx, 0);
  } else if (resp.metadata.response_type === "enum") {
    enums.push(resp)
    //rearrangeArray(entry.response, idx, 0);
  }
});
var results = labels.concat(enums)
```

Comment: Ah interesting, I think I do prefer this, it definitely avoids the necessity for multiple loops. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom comparison. Note that `sort` is not necessarily stable, so this solution can change the order of 'enum's.

```js
function compareValues(a, b) {
  return (a > b) ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
}

function weighItem(x) {
  var meta = x.metadata;
  if (meta.response_type === "enum") return 0;
  if (meta.response_label) return 1;
  return 2;
}

function compareResponses(a, b) {
  return compareValues(weighItem(a), weighItem(b));
}


var arr = [
  { metadata: {
    response_type: "enum",
    response_label: ""
  } },
  { metadata: {
    response_type: "not_enum",
    response_label: ""
  } },
  { metadata: {
    response_type: "enum",
    response_label: "asd"
  } },
  { metadata: {
    response_type: "not_enum",
    response_label: "fgh"
  } }
];

arr.sort(compareResponses);

// Log the output
$('pre').text(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```